# Why does this conditional feel wrong?

Tags: past-perfect, conditionals

The following phrase is part of a narrative in past tense. My mind has been going in circles around it, so any help would be appreciated.

- *He sighed and replied quickly, as if **he had had** only a few seconds'
  time before John **changed** his mind*

I'm not sure about the items marked with bold font, above. Something feels wrong. Any input?

Comment: "as if he had" is conditional. "as if he had had" is past conditional.

Comment: Sounds off to me, since if the hypothetical "few seconds" *were* to have existed at all, they wouldn't meaningfully have ***preceded*** his sighing and replying quickly. The pluperfect construction would make more sense in, say, *He jabbered excitedly, as if he had had a few drinks before our meeting.*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've given *he* a name to make for easier reference:

> *Bob sighed and replied quickly, as if **he had had** only a few seconds'
>      time before John **changed** his mind*.

This sentence is not wrong but the following might be better:

- Bob sighed and replied quickly, as if he had only a few seconds
  before John would change his mind.

The past perfect in the original example makes it sound as if Bob might have already had the seconds. But in this actual situation these seconds are about to occur, they haven't occurred already. I think *would* representing a future in the past is better than *changed* here. It clearly orientates the notional sequence of events. Lastly,  we do not really need the word *time* in this sentence. It is a bit confusing because we expect to see *time* used this way in preposition phrases using the preposition *in*, where it represents a point in time, not a period:

- I'll phone you in a few minutes time.

---

<sup>**Grammar note:**</sup>

<sup>This sentence isn't a conditional. The Adjunct *as if he had ... mind* is  an Adjunct of comparison, not a conditional Adjunct. Notice that the truth of the main clause *Bob sighed and replied quickly* does not depend in any sense on the *as if* clause being true. We can compare it with:</sup>

<sup>- Bob sighed and replied quickly if his interrogators asked him embarrassing questions.</sup>

<sup>In the sentence above we get the impression that Bob's sighing and answering is caused by the interrogators. The questions are a precondition for the sighing. This is very different from the Original Poster's sentence.</sup>

<sup>The *Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* (Huddleston & Pullum, 2002) classify *as if* as a compound preposition. CaGEL notes that when the main clause is present tense, the verb forms in the *as if* clause may be backshifted (p 1152). In other words we may see the forms we see in *if*-clauses in so-called remote conditionals:</sup>

<sup>- She always looks at me as if she hated me. (*as if*- clause as comparative Adjunct)</sup>

<sup>- She wouldn't be so nice to me if she hated me. (*if*-clause as conditional Adjunct)</sup>

<sup>Notice here that the main clause must have *would* in the remote conditional.</sup>

<sup>Now, although we often see a modally remote past simple in *as if*-clauses when the matrix (main clause) verb is present simple, we only very rarely see modally remote past perfects in *as if*-clauses, when the matrix verb is *past* simple (CaGEL, p. 1153). Very often it is not possible:</sup>

<sup>- She looked relaxed, as if she skated every day.</sup>

<sup>- She looked relaxed, as if she'd skated every day.</sup>

<sup>In the second sentence above we can only understand *as if she'd skated every day* to refer to an earlier time, before the time we are actually talking about. It cannot be interpreted similarly to the first example. It cannot refer to general time at the time that she looked relaxed.</sup>

Comment: I am watching Bob signing right at this moment and talking on the phone to let the other party know the news.  "Bob is signing now as if he **had** only a few seconds before John changes his mind". Do we need to use "has" instead of "had" in the sentence?

Comment: @DigitalDracula I don't think the notional "sequence of events" applys to hypothetical or irreal subjunctive mood. I am not saying Araucaria's rephrased sentence is wrong, but I am asking myself why it is necessary to rephrase it except for the "would" part.

Comment: this has changed the meaning or emphasis, it is not more correct.

Comment: That is one way to improve it, but (to a British English speaker) it "feels" like it should have been "He sighed and replied quickly, as if he had had only a few seconds' time before John **had** changed his mind." Either way, the tenses are better matched. Without more context, we don't know what situation the original author was trying to describe.

Comment: @alephzero I thought the context should be fairly clear, but I'm happy to elaborate: John makes a suggestion. Bob, after a short delay, sighs and replies in a hurry before John changes his mind and retracts the suggestion.

Comment: @Rathony, Digital Dracula, I've added a grammar note in case it is useful.

Comment: @alephzero I don't disagree with the grammaticality or felicity of your alternative sentence, but it does rather give the reading that John had changed his mind *before* Bob spoke, which is not really what we're trying to convey.

Comment: @Rathony No, that's fine. It's very common to have a "modally remote" past tensein the *as if* adjunct, when the main clause is present tense. So this doesn't strongly lead us to think that the *as if*-proposition is hyptothetically happening *before* the signing. However, it is very rare for the *as if* adjunct to have a modally remote past perfect, which can lead us to favour the temporal anteriority interpretation. Notice that even if the *as if*-clause is impossible, we still often use a past simple, not a past perfect: ... (cont)

Comment: @Rathony ... So for example "She looked at me as if I was a monster" is just as natural, if not more so, than "She looked at me as if I'd been a monster". English is weird!

Answer (score 2):

As a general bit of writing advice, rather than grammar discussion; if a sentence won't settle, just rewrite the damned thing, eg;

> He sighed, but feeling rushed, he replied before John changed his mind.

It's not the same sense, but no-one else cares what you originally wrote, so just crack on with more of your manuscript ;)

Comment: That's probably what I will ultimately do, but now I got curious about this :)

Comment: Then this site may not be great for your novel! Back to the word mines! :)

Answer (score 1):

Feels alright; here's how I see the two uses

"if he had" would feel normal with any other verb;

> if he had seen the ball, he would have ducked.

the second "had" comes because you "have time";

> He has a few seconds before...

so it's ok to move that into the past tense and conbine it with the first, 'conditional had.'

Comment: I suppose "if he had see" is a typo for "if he had seen".

Comment: @alephzero thank you, yes. It was a typo. Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that the tense used with "replied" should match that of the conditional, at least for the events described in this sentence.

So, the corrected sentence would read:

> He sighed and replied quickly, as if he had only a few seconds' time
>   before John changed his mind.

In other tenses:

> He sighs and replies quickly, as if he has has only a few seconds'
>   time before John changes his mind.
>
> He had sighed and replied quickly, as if he had had only a few seconds'
>   time before John would change his mind.

All of this ignores the underlying issue that John can't seem to make a decision.

Comment: Your present-tense sentence (#2) doesn't read right to me -- I think I'd drop the second has. Sentence #1 seems valid, too -- a single 'had' seems acceptable.